# Qt - How to Transfer QListView Items to another QListView?

Tags: qt, qt4.7, qlistview, model-view, qlineedit

I have a **QLineEdit**, **2 QPush buttons** (Add & Remove Buttons) and a **QListView**. The Text which i am entering in the **QLineEdit will gets added** in the **QListView** when the **add button is clicked**. And if I'm selecting any one of the **Item from the QListView** and click the **Remove Button** the selected item will be removed. I finished these things and it works fine. **Now i want to add a another QListView and if am Double clicking the QListView Items (QListView 1) the items should be transfered** (items in the QListView 1 should be removed completely) **to the new QListView (QListView 2) and vice versa.** plz help me with your suggestions. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example.h**

```
class Example : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Example(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Example();

private slots:
     void on_listView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index);
     void on_listView_2_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index);

private:
    QStandardItemModel *model;  // This model is used when the add button is clicked.
    QStandardItemModel *listViewModel;
};
```

**Example.cpp**

```
void Example::on_listView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{  
    QStandardItem *Item1;
    Items1 = new QStandardItem();

    Items1->setData(ui->listView->currentIndex().data(), Qt::DisplayRole );
    Items1->setEditable( false );

    listViewModel->appendRow( Items1 );
    listViewModel->sort( 0, Qt::AscendingOrder );
    ui->listView_2->setModel( listViewModel );

    model->removeRow( ui->listView->currentIndex().row() );
}

void Example::on_listView_2_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QStandardItem *Items2;
    Items2 = new QStandardItem();
    Items2->setData( ui->listView_2->currentIndex().data(), Qt::DisplayRole );
    Items2->setEditable( false);

    model->appendRow( Items2 );
    model->sort( 0,Qt::AscendingOrder );

    ui->listView->setModel( model );
    model->removeRow( ui->listView_2->currentIndex().row() );

}
```

Comment: Why do you even bother using `QListView` when then still using an archaic way to insert items? Just use `QListWidget` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A more extensible way would be to create a custom model (possibly inheriting the `QStringListModel` if that suits your needs) and then implementing `moveRows` and/or the Drag&Drop facilities.